# Sort API Response without Storing the Data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, sorting

I am using below code to call a GET API and then sort the Response with one of the object listed inside. I was told to convert the response to a ARRAY first then apply the sort function but it seems difficult and im missing some thing to sort the generated Array. Please help me, been trying for many days.

My Code:

```js
url2 = "https://SampleAPI";

function fetchdata(){
  fetch(url2)
    .then(response=>{
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data=> {
    console.log(data.data) // Getting the "Unsroted Response" Here
  })
  };
  fetchdata(); //

const sortedResponse = ListModels.sort(function(a, b) { return parseInt(a.associateId) - parseInt(b.associateId) });
console.log("SORTED: ", sortedResponse) // Using to SORT THE RESPONSE WITH "associateId"
```

API Response for Above JS Code:

```
{
ListModels:(4) [
{
searchRank:0,
firstName:"Micheal",
lastName:"Brook",
associateId:"40",
payRateType:"Cost-only",
doctorStatus:null,
contractStartDate:"0001-01-01T00:00:00"
},
{
searchRank:0,
firstName:"Travis",
lastName:"Mayn",
associateId:"20",
payRateType:"Samp-only",
doctorStatus:null,
contractStartDate:"0001-01-01T00:00:00"
},
{
searchRank:0,
firstName:"Berry",
lastName:"Brooks",
associateId:"43",
payRateType:"Samp-only",
doctorStatus:null,
contractStartDate:"0001-01-01T00:00:00"
},
{
searchRank:0,
firstName:"Kim",
lastName:"Reed",
associateId:"25",
payRateType:"Samp-only",
doctorStatus:null,
contractStartDate:"0001-01-01T00:00:00"
}
],
totalRecord:4
}
```

I want to SORT above API response with "associateId" but with my Sorting line, im getting Error.
Please help me, i was told to hit the API Endpoint and sort without storing the response in CODE.

Error:

```
> error: Uncaught ReferenceError: ListModels is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the sorting inside the response handler:

```
url2 = "https://SampleAPI";

function fetchdata(){
  fetch(url2)
    .then(response=>{
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data=> {
    console.log(data.data) // Getting the "Unsroted Response" Here
    const list = data.data;
    const sortedResponse = list.sort(function(a, b) { return parseInt(a.associateId) - parseInt(b.associateId) });
    console.log("SORTED: ", sortedResponse) // Using to SORT THE RESPONSE WITH "associateId"  })
  };
  fetchdata(); //
```

The operations just after `fetchdata` are executed before the response comes from the server.

Comment: Im getting the same error, >>> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: ListModels is not defined  .Please help

Comment: ListModels appears undefined because there's no mention in your (upper) script, and the API response (lower snippet) is not a valid JSON. So, why you want to use this ListModels?